# Azure AD userAssertion: Token missing scope "Directory.Read.All"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have a Web API and a UI application that used `ADAL` library to call the Web API.

I already gave `DELEGATED PERMISSIONS` (`Read directory data`) for both Web API and UI application while registering the apps to Azure AD.

[image]

I have below code in Web API to save Token for log-In user,

```
private void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
             new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
             {
                 Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                 TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { SaveSigninToken = true, ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"] }
             });
    }
```

Now in Web API controllers, I am trying to get token to access Microsoft AD Graph API using below code,

```
var bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;
            string userName = "test@onmicrosoft.com";
            string userAccessToken = bootstrapContext.Token;
            UserAssertion userAssertion = new UserAssertion(bootstrapContext.Token, "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer", userName);

            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant));
            var clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);

            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", clientCred, userAssertion);
            accessToken = result.AccessToken;
```

The above code giving me token back but the scope values is below,

```
`scp: "User.Read"`
```

Question - Why the token not giving directory access (`Directory.Read.All`) as I already set Directory access?

```
`scp: "Directory.Read.All User.Read"`
```

**Update:**

I am missing Grant Permission for Read Directory Data under `DELEGATED PERMISSIONS`. After giving `Grant Permission` I am able to get token with scope `scp: "Directory.Read.All User.Read"`

[image]

Comment: Do you want to use AAD Graph API or Microsoft Graph ? The permssions you set is for Azure AD Graph API,not Microsoft Graph. Also,the scope for the v1 endpoint can be defined in Manifest and you can change the `value` of   `oauth2Permissions`. Once it had been defined , it will keep the value .

Comment: Any proccess on this case ?

Comment: @Wayne, I am able to get read directory data permission after clicking Grant Permission. See my update on question. Thanks for all you help

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use Microsoft Graph API ,not Azure AD Graph API.

However, based on that the screenshot you post in this question is a `v1 enpoint` AAD Application, it does nothing about Microsoft Graph API which you're trying to approaching. So, whatever you changed on this application, the result shouldn  be same. I suggest you  register `v2 enpoint` Application in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/

Here is [a document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview) which shows how to get auth tokens for using Microsoft Graph.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply, are you saying this is wrong `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer`

Comment: i would like to use Azure AD Graph API

Comment: what I need to change for `value of oauth2Permissions`

Comment: @Sorry for my misunderstanding, If you want to use AAD Graph API, the scope is `defined` in  value of `oauthPermissions`.

Comment: what value, can u suggest? how to set

Comment: You can go to Azure portal > application registrations > your app > Manifest. Joonas Blog may be helpful: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad

Comment: current value is `"value": "user_impersonation"'

Comment: Yep, its default value is `user_impersonation` So, I want to know what app are you using to get auth token. Are you sure that  you're using this v1 endpoint application to get auth token?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167532/discussion-between-wayne-yang-msft-and-user584018).

Comment: can u help, I have a web api app which I register within Azure AD, but I can I can also see my application here https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/. how to know v1 or v2?

Comment: Well, Make sense! Applications registered in Azure portal are all v1 endpoint.  Applications registered in `apps.dev.microsoft.com` are all v2 endpoint.